# Autofilling form field using URL

Tags: forms, post, wget, fill

i have been trying for past 4 hours and cannot succeed.

I have been trying to autofill ACCOUNT PIN # in http://bluffmycall.com/

But its just not taking it, i have tried using

```
http://bluffmycall.com/?pin=1111
http://bluffmycall.com/login/?has_errors=invalid&next=/account/&pin=1111
```

i tried

```
wget  http://bluffmycall.com --post-data="pin=1111"

wget  http://bluffmycall.com/login/?has_errors=invalid&next=/account/ --post-data="pin=1111"

wget  http://bluffmycall.com/login/?has_errors=invalid&next=/account/ --post-data="id_pin=1111"
```

It all of no use, i even tried curl.

I need a way to have url which can just prepopulate the field with ACCOUNT PIN #. Any help will be appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send the PIN to the `action` URL of the form:

```
wget http://bluffmycall.com/login/bypass/ --post-data="pin=1111"
```

By itself this probably won't do anything. Logging in creates a session, and you need to get the cookie that identifies the session. Then subsequent `wget` calls will need to send back the session cookie.

Comment: You are the MAN. Thank you. This is what i did: http://bluffmycall.com/login/bypass/?pin=1111

Comment: An this worked flawlessly and i can do it with wget too.  wget http://bluffmycall.com/login/bypass/?pin=1111

Comment: Just click on the check, it will become green.